# How to authorize an app if is fan of an specific fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm working on a contest app (http://apps.facebook.com/retoiphonetigo/) the goal is to increase the fans number of the Tigo Fan Page. Is there any option to show on the canvas app  the app only if the user is already fan of the Fan Page.

Just like when the contests where made with the like button, anyone can't "like" if isn't fan of the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the old [pages.isFan documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/):

```
You can now issue a HTTP GET request to /USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID to check if a user is a page of a fan.
```